# Liferay shopping portlet and taglib's categories integration

Tags: liferay, taglib

I have a task to integrate categories and tags to shopping items, so that I could use Categories and Tags Navigation to let user sort them.

I've successfully implemented tags and they work nice. But when I use the same approach to categories, something goes wrong and clicking on a category name in Categories Navigation leads to "The category could not be found." error message.
Specifically, after adding 
    `<supported-public-render-parameter>categoryId</supported-public-render-parameter`
to portlet-ext.xml.
I assume that there are some name conflicts with "categoryId" in internal shopping portlet categories implementation.

Just spent 3 days digging sources and still do not know where to go.

Any advice or "dig-direction?"

Comment: Can you answer your own question so that it is marked as resolved? This would help other members as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, finally figured it out by myself. Shopping portlet uses the same "categoryId" parametr and always checks it. And of course Categories Navigation adds its own "categoryId" parametr and shopping portlet fails the check and throws an exception.